# Why are getter/setter no longer working after copying an object with the spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, object, spread-syntax

In the following snippet, the spread syntax works in a manner that I don't quite understand:

```js
let obj = {
  set setName(name){
    obj.name = name
  },
  get myName() {
    return obj.name
  }
}
    
obj.setName = 'Jon Doe'

let spread_obj = {...obj}
spread_obj.setName = 'Marion Luke'
console.log('spread_obj name', spread_obj.myName) // spread_obj name Jon Doe 

let create_obj = Object.create(obj)
create_obj.setName = 'Marion Luke'
console.log('create_obj name', create_obj.myName) // create_obj name Marion Luke
```

Can you explain why the reassignment of the name does not work in such a case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spreading an object does not copy getter and setter methods - rather, the spread operation only *gets* the property (that is, it *calls* the getter, if there is one), and assigns the result to the resulting object (the `spread_obj`, here), just like a normal object, without any getters or setters. You can see this if you put log statements inside the setter and getter. The resulting `spread_obj` has a `setName` property of `undefined` because `setName` is only a setter method, which doesn't return anything.

```js
let obj = {
  set setName(name){
    console.log('setting ' + name);
    this.name = name
  },
  get myName() {
    console.log('getting');
    return this.name
  }
}

obj.setName = 'Jon Doe'
console.log('About to spread');
let spread_obj = {...obj}
console.log('Done spreading. spread_obj contents is:');
console.log(spread_obj);
spread_obj.setName = 'Marion Luke' // No "setting" log statement
```

Also note that if you want to use the second part of your code, you should probably change the setter and getter methods to refer to `this` rather than to `obj`, otherwise the results could be unintuitive; your getter and setter methods area always referring to the `.name` property on `obj`, rather than the `.name` property on the standard calling context (that is, to `spread_obj` or to `create_obj`). When you try to assign to `spread_obj.setName`, you actually change the *original* `obj`'s `.name` property:

```js
let obj = {
  set setName(name){
    obj.name = name
  },
  get myName() {
    return obj.name
  }
}
obj.setName = 'Jon Doe'

let create_obj1 = Object.create(obj)
create_obj1.setName = 'Marion Luke1'

let create_obj2 = Object.create(obj)
create_obj2.setName = 'Marion Luke2'
// "Marion Luke2", but we're logging the property from the "first" object!
console.log('create_obj name', create_obj1.name)
```

Fix by referring to `this` instead of `obj`:

```js
let obj = {
  set setName(name){
    this.name = name
  },
  get myName() {
    return this.name
  }
}
obj.setName = 'Jon Doe'

let create_obj1 = Object.create(obj)
create_obj1.setName = 'Marion Luke1'

let create_obj2 = Object.create(obj)
create_obj2.setName = 'Marion Luke2'
console.log(create_obj1.name)
```

Comment: I used obj instead of this because I thought that setters and getters are actually copied. now I realized that something like `Object.assign(SomeClassInstance.prototype, obj)` won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

the select answer is wrong.

- getter/setter is not method, it is special properties.
- ...spread and object.assign will not work, just because they treat getter/setter like normal enumerable property, they
  copy the 'value' of it, so getter/setter will fail.

if you want to copy it, you can refer undercore.js the extend method:

this is my assign code:

```js
const assign = (ob, ...o) => {
  o.forEach(obj=>{if (typeof obj !== 'undefined')
  Object.defineProperties(ob, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));}) 
  return ob;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @CertainPerformances explanation, I would add that the behavior seems more sensible when using the getters/setters a more traditionally by having one name for both get and set.

For example when your object looks like this, everything works a little better (at least on the surface):

```js
let obj = {
  set name(name){        // setter and getter are accessed with the same property
    this._name = name
  },
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
}

obj.name = 'Jon Doe'
let spread_obj = {...obj}
spread_obj.name = 'Marion Luke'

// this seems more expected
console.log('spread_obj name', spread_obj.name)

// but this is still a little strange because
// Jon Doe is still there
console.log(spread_obj)
```

It's seems like a lot of work, but since object spread only takes enumerable properties, you can make `_name` non-enumerable. Then everything seems a little more sensible:

```js
let obj = {
  set name(name){
    this._name = name
  },
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
}
Object.defineProperty(obj, '_name', {
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
});

obj.name = 'Jon Doe'

let spread_obj = {...obj}
spread_obj.name = 'Marion Luke'

// now spread_obj only has a name prop:
console.log(spread_obj)

// and obj too:
console.log(obj)
```