# destructuring losing getter definition

Tags: javascript

Simplified version of my code. I define getter-setter for **var1**, then I destructure it to **child**.

I expect **child** to get the definition of **var1** but it does not. I expect the last line to print 40 40 when I set **child.var1** but it prints 30 40 instead.
If I use **Object.assign** the parent will get var2.

How do I retain the getter-setter of **var1** on **child** but also I want the **parent** not to get **var2**?

```js
let val = 10;

let parent = {
  set var1(_val) {
    val = _val;
  },
  get var1() {
    return val;
  }
}

console.log(parent.var1); // 10
parent.var1 = 20;
console.log(parent.var1); // 20

let child = { ...parent, var2: 1 };
parent.var1 = 30;
child.var1 = 40;
console.log(parent.var1, child.var1); // 30 40
```

Comment: https://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html

Comment: A slightly more authoritative link: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread, which links on to https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md which tells us what `...rest` desugars into. `let child = { ...parent, var2: 1 }` should do the exact same as `Object.assign({}, parent, {var2: 1}};`, and Object.assign [explicitly invokes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#description) getters/setters: you can't copy getter functions this way, only the values you get _from_ those getters.

Comment: `let child = {...parent}` is equivalent to `let child = {var1: parent.var1, var2: parent.var2}`. As you can see `parent.var1` is being computed and assigned to `child.var1` as a regular value.

Answer (score 1):

The spreading of the `parent` object, is what cause the unexpected changed behavior.

It seems like the official documentation is laking in this part (I might didn't dig enough).

here's an explanation [from CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692351/why-are-getter-setter-no-longer-working-after-copying-an-object-with-the-spread)

> Spreading an object does not copy getter and setter methods - rather, the spread operation only gets the property (that is, it calls the getter, if there is one), and assigns the result to the resulting object (the spread_obj, here), just like a normal object, without any getters or setters. You can see this if you put log statements inside the setter and getter. The resulting spread_obj has a setName property of undefined because setName is only a setter method, which doesn't return anything.

This is your answer, but I could not find anything to back this up in the docs.

here's your code snippet with some additions, it might be helpful

```js
let val = 10;

let parent = {
  set var1(_val) {
      val = _val;
},
    get var1() {
        return val;
    }
}

console.log(parent.var1); // 10
parent.var1 = 20;
console.log(parent.var1); // 20

let child1 = parent;
console.log(child1.var1 == parent.var1); // true
//  child1 is a reference of parent .. no surprise 

let child2 = { ...parent, var2: 1 };
console.log(parent.var1 == child2.var1); // true
// here child2 holds a field name 'var1' with reference to 'val'
// there for the expression is true --> value returned from the parent getter (= val), is equal to the child2.var1 reference (= val)

child2.var1 = 10;
parent.var1 = 30;
// here we override the the reference to 'val' with the value 40.
console.log(parent.var1 == child2.var1); // false
```